# MySQL Caching

Tags: .net, mysql, database, enterprise-library

Last night I added a parameter to a stored procedure in a mySQL database.  I accessed it, messed up the parameter, and decided to remove the parameter again, for testing.  Still minutes after re-creating the procedure without the parameter, my command object was still complaining about a missing parameter.  Is this mySQL, MySQL/Connector, ADO, or Enterprise library's fault, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923979/is-mysql-caching-occurring-how-to-fix-it if you don't have MySQL privileges .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default MySQL caches queries in your stored procedures. See if Query Cache is enabled:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%'
```

Stored procedure calls are not cached by MySQL, but if `query_cache_type` is ON this will affect caching of queries issued from within the procedure. Possibly causing MySQL to return the same results for a couple of minutes. Try flushing the cache, or better yet, reset the query cache to remove all queries if your updated procedure keeps returning the previous result set:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE
```

That should eliminate any caching by MySQL server.

Next time this happens you could execute the procedure by hand through another tool that does not use MySQL/Connector or Enterprise Library. That will tell you if the old result set is cached by either MySQL or the drivers and application blocks in your application.

***Edit:*** please read the comments below, by desertwebdesign. After recreating the sproc, drop the connection. Connection pooling may keep the connection open, so it's probably best to kill the  connection from MySQL. Most query browsers have a tab that allow you to kill connections in MySQL if you log in with process/super privileges.

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
KILL CONNECTION thread_id
```

Comment: The QUERY CACHE is NOT the same as the procedure cache. There is no MySQL variable/function to control the procedure cache. The only way to reload it is by invalidating it. This will only happen when a procedure is dropped, added or changed with the ALTER PROCEDURE command (which doesn't allow you to change the body of the procedure). The cache will be rebuilt on your next connection, assuming you don't use pooling or persistent connections. If you ran an UPDATE on the mysql.proc table to change the body, I don't think that invalidates the cache or not. I need to read more source code first.